# ParaView: How to fix "PNGWriter only supports unsigned char and unsigned short inputs"?

Tags: paraview

I am trying to convert from `.vtk` to a series of `.png` slices (i.e., P images each with a resolution of MxN). I am currently using ParaView to attempt to accomplish this. However, upon attempting to save the data as `.png`, I receive the following error:

`vtkkPNGWriter (0x7fa8339b4620) PNGWriter only supports unsigned char and unsigned short inputs`

The steps I am currently attempting are:

1. Load the data
2. Apply the filter: Convert from cell to point data
3. Apply the filter: Resample to Image
4. Save Data as `.png`
5. Error as specified above.

This error appears regardless of data format (i.e., jpg, png, etc.). However, it successfully outputs a `.mhd` file that is readable with Slicer.

Is there a fix for this, is it just my dataset, or is this a known bug?

I am also open to suggestions for ways of easily generating the sequence of images I need so I can throw them into something like ImageJ. Currently looking at python vtk and SimpleITK.

**ParaView Versions Tested:**

- Linux 5.4.0
- Windows 5.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a calculator filter to convert your data to unsigned char:

- Load the data
- Apply the filter: Convert from cell to point data
- Apply the filter: Resample to Image
- Add a calculator filter
- Output type : unsigned char
- Formula : yourOwnArray
- Apply
- Save Data as .png

Comment: Thank you for your response. For the "Output Type" I do not see any option to specify that. The only option is "Attribute Type" and the options are point data and cell data. Can you please clarify where I should be able to set the output type?

Comment: Make sure to use the last release of ParaView, ie 5.9.0 and Click on the cogwheel to show advanced options

Comment: Alright. This is feature that doesn't exist in the older versions. Good to know.